# How to localize App Store meta data for Phonegap app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cordova, localization

i'm currently wondering how to add more localizations to my PhoneGap App on the App Store. So it is already deployed, and in App Store it shows under Languages, right under the Icon "English, Spanish" but I never changed any configs or so to acheive this. I found in my xCode-project /App_NAME/Resources a en.lproj and es.lproj folder with Localisation.strings.

The standard way I found so far would be to do [this](http://www.daveoncode.com/2010/05/15/iphone-applications-localization/).

But for some Reason those folder I create never appear in xCode. What am I doing wrong, and why can't I add more of these ominous XX.lproj-folders?

I'm totally stuck.

I can do javascript localisations for the app itsself but without this app-store languages I can't get my meta-data translated...

Any experience highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is to do it from javascript since you're using PhoneGap.
retrieve the device/userAgent language (or locale, or simply ask the user for a preferred language) and then edit the content accordingly.

Comment: Ok, to get the metadata translated just create a new version, upload it, then go to details screen of that version. Then dropdown 'choose another language' press 'Japanese(jp) add' and fill in what's missing in japanese.. dead simple. This is only possible when thwe state of your version is after 'Waiting for upload' and before 'Ready for sale' (not 100% sure about the last state, so just do it after you uploaded).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to localize app store meta data, your app, or your marketing content there are tools out there now to speed the process such as [TraductoPro](http://www.traductoapp.com), which also has built-in human translation ordering services. It even automates or 'macronizes' your code, making the xcode strings localizable. It's a Mac app, simple to use.